# Python create nested JSON from flat SQL data

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to build a nested JSON structure of sales orders and order details from flat SQL data.

FLAT SQL DATA:

| id | created_on | customer | total | detail_id | item | qty | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2023-12-27 21:36:24 | Jed Clampett | 346.72 | 39 | Pen | 2 | FILLED |
| 30 | 2023-12-27 21:36:24 | Jed Clampett | 346.72 | 38 | Fob | 1 | FILLED |
| 32 | 2024-01-30 19:37:42 | Bobby Fisher | 670.82 | 40 | Fob | 6 | FILLED |
| 33 | 2024-01-30 20:08:23 | Jed Clampett | 229.51 | 42 | Pen | 1 | TRANSIT |
| 33 | 2024-01-30 20:08:23 | Jed Clampett | 229.51 | 41 | Fob | 1 | FILLED |
| 34 | 2024-01-30 21:08:34 | Bobby Fisher | 112.09 | 43 | Fob | 1 | FILLED |

DESIRED JSON DATA:

```
[
   {
      'id': 30,
      'created_on': '2023-12-27 21:36:24',
      'customer': 'Jed Clampett',
      'total': 346.72,
      'details': [
         { 'detail_id': 39, 'item': 'Pen', 'qty': 2, 'status': 'FILLED' },
         { 'detail_id': 38, 'item': 'Fob', 'qty': 1, 'status': 'FILLED' }
      ]
   },
   {
      'id': 32,
      'created_on': '2024-01-30 19:37:42',
      'customer': 'Bobby Fisher',
      'total': 670.82,
      'details': [
         { 'detail_id': 40, 'item': 'Fob', 'qty': 6, 'status': 'FILLED' }
      ]
   },
   {
      'id': 33,
      'created_on': '2024-01-30 20:08:23',
      'customer': 'Jed Clampett',
      'total': 229.51,
      'details': [
         { 'detail_id': 42, 'item': 'Pen', 'qty': 1, 'status': 'TRANSIT' },
         { 'detail_id': 41, 'item': 'Fob', 'qty': 1, 'status': 'FILLED' }
      ]
   },
   {
      'id': 34,
      'created_on': '2024-01-30 21:08:34',
      'customer': 'Bobby Fisher',
      'total': 112.09,
      'details': [
         { 'detail_id': 43, 'item': 'Fob', 'qty': 1, 'status': 'FILLED' }
      ]
   }
]
```

CURRENT CODE:

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
        """
        select * from aocsoft.v_sales_orders_and_details where store_id = %s order by created_on desc
        """
        , [request.user.store.id])

        def dictfetchall(cursor):
            columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
            return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        
        res = dictfetchall(cursor)

        package = []
        for r in res:
            if r['id'] not in package?????: <-- Need to check package array objects for id
                package.append(
                    { 
                        'id': r['id'],
                        'created_on': r['created_on'],
                        'details': []????? <-- Need to add associated details to this array
                    }
                )

        print(package)
        
        return JsonResponse(package, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM aocsoft.v_sales_orders_and_details 
        WHERE store_id = %s 
        ORDER BY created_on DESC
    """, [request.user.store.id])

    def dictfetchall(cursor):
        columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
        return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    res = dictfetchall(cursor)

    orders = {}
    for r in res:
        order_id = r['id']
        detail = {
            'detail_id': r['detail_id'],
            'item': r['item'],
            'qty': r['qty'],
            'status': r['status']
        }
        if order_id not in orders:
            orders[order_id] = {
                'id': r['id'],
                'created_on': r['created_on'],
                'customer': r['customer'],
                'total': r['total'],
                'details': [detail]
            }
        else:
            orders[order_id]['details'].append(detail)

    # Convert the orders dictionary to a list of its values
    package = list(orders.values())

    print(package)

    return JsonResponse(package, safe=False)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'm accustomed to javascript and am trying to understand pythons syntax... This is very helpful.